# Using Ansible iterate over json returned from Docker API

Tags: linux, docker, ansible

Hi I have a playbook like the following and I am trying to parse json output from docker api, and haven't had luck yet. Id like to parse the Id field and use it as input to docker exec. My end result, is to get a report of all containers running, with their environment variables.

```
- hosts: devtest.log.mycompany.com



 tasks: 

- name: Get containers
  command:  curl  --insecure --cert-type PEM --cert /etc/docker/server-cert.pem  --key /etc/docker/server-key.pem  "https://127.0.0.1:2376/v1.22/containers/json?all=1"
  register: containers

- debug: msg="{{ containers.stdout }}"

- name: Get ENV Vars
  command: docker exec -t {{ item }} printenv
  with_items: "{{ containers.stdout|json_query|('Id[*]'') }}"
```

Comment: Instead of using `docker exec` you might want to use the inspect endpoint at `/containers/{id}/json`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/#operation/ContainerInspect - please note that you'll get different results compared to `printenv`. Then a note about json_query: did you try `..stdout|from_json|json_query('[*].Id')`? See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter

Comment: Thanks @gesellix. I'll try that. That worked, moving the [*].id. Feel free to post an answer, and I will mark it as answered.

Comment: thanks @Codemiester!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use a syntax like this:

```
...stdout | from_json | json_query('[*].Id')
```

The important bit is to iterate over the json array by starting the query with `[*]`.

See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter for details.